# HTML Page Doesn't Show Up on Springboot Application

Tags: maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a registration page. The website is very simple, homepage will be returning signup page and when clicked "Submit" it should save it to the database. But I'm having trouble with getting the page.

**Applicant.java**

```
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
    import java.util.Date;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "bayilik_basvuru")
    public class Applicant {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int id;
        @NotBlank(message = "İsim Soyisim Girilmelidir.")
        @Column(name = "isim_soyisim")
        private String adSoyad;

        public Applicant() {

        }

        public String getAdSoyad() {
            return adSoyad;
        }

        public void setAdSoyad(String adSoyad) {
            this.adSoyad = adSoyad;
        }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class HomeContoller {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicantDAO dao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView getApplicationPage(){
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        Applicant applicant = new Applicant();
        model.addObject("applicant",applicant);
        model.setViewName("index");

        return model;
    }


    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String saveApplicant(@Valid Applicant applicant, BindingResult result){
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-student";
        }

        dao.save(applicant);
        return "index";
    }
}
```

**Index.html -> form's piece,**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Bayilik Ön Başvuru Formu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../css/style.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{../css/roboto-font.css}" />

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-horizantal" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${applicant}"
                                  method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">İsim Soyisim</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
           <input type="text" th:field="*{adSoyad}" class="form-control" /> <!-- it gives error at this line at the start of the th:field-->
           <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('adSoyad')}" th:errors="*{adSoyad}" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been dealing with this for hours. I've compared it to many examples and html file looks good, controller looks good I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**In my pom file I have thymeleaf;**

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
<dependendcies>
```

By the way the error is this;

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Thu Oct 31 01:40:47 EET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringInputGeneralFieldTagProcessor' (template: "index" - line 27, col 56) // this line is the same line I showed on the index.html file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there was an hierarchy problem on the project. Code worked after I fixed the hierarchy of files.

Thanks to repliers for their attempt to help but they couldn't know the core of the problem since I didn't attach the hierarchy's screenshot on the question.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the annotation `@ModelAttribute` on your /save endpoint . try using it like :

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public String saveApplicant( @Valid @ModelAttribute("applicant") Applicant applicant, BindingResult result){
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "add-student";
    }

    dao.save(applicant);
    return "index";
}
```

In your thymeleaf template `th:object="${applicant}"` expression declares the model object to use for collecting the form data. So , in your controller you have to use the annotation `@ModelAttribute` to bind the **Applicant** object to the incoming form content.

Comment: I changed the controller but problem continues. I don't think it's from the POST method though, page doesn't even load so there must be a problem with the GET function which I am not seeing.

Answer (score 2):

Change your get method to properly add the object:

```
@GetMapping("/") //simpler, more informative
public String getApplicationPage(Model model){
   model.addAttribute("applicant", new Applicant());  //note method name
   return "index";
}
```

Look at Project Lombok to greatly simplify your beans.  You are missing a getter and setter for your `id` property and an annotation of `@Getter` and `@Setter` on the class would remove a lot of boilerplate.

You would also want the `@ModelAttribute` annotation on your post method for the `Applicant` parameter.

In the future, also please post your full stack trace.

Comment: The problem was beacuse of a hierarchy problem. It's hard to solve problems like this since the ide doesn't really help with it, I figured it out after I changed return view's name to something that wasn't in template folder. Thank you for your interest though, I really appriciate your help.